# Stepwise regression based on F-statistic in R

Tags: r, stepwise-regression, f-statistic

I know that the `stepAIC` function in R allows us to perform stepwise regression but I was wondering if there's any option (or other function) to perform a F-statistic based stepwise regression ?

I've looked in the help of the `stepAIC` function but didn't find any answer.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Questions that are only about software (e.g. error messages, code or packages, etc.)
are generally off topic here. If you have a substantive machine learning or
statistical question, please edit to clarify.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll keep that in mind for my next questions.

Comment: Stepwise selection based on F-tests isn't going to be any better than stepwise selection based on the AIC or any other metric.  To a first approximation, all stepwise selection is bad (cf, [Algorithms for automatic model selection](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/20856/7290)).

Answer (score 1):

So I've found the answer I was looking for.
The `dropterm` function for the `MASS` package allows us to perform backwards variable selection using any statistic we want. The equivalent function `addterm` allows to do the same with forward regression.

To do so, you simply need to add the argument `test=c("none","Chisq","F")` for the statistic you want. Keep in mind that the F-statistic selection only works for model of the class `lm` and `aov`.